# Pandas percent change based on previous column value identified by datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'd like to compute 1-, 2-, and 3-year annualized dividend growth (geometric mean) within each group of 'tickers' in the below dataframe, where the growth is always with respect to the most recent time period within each group.

I have:

```
   ticker        date  dividends
0       A   3/31/2019       0.63
1       A   3/31/2018       0.56
2       A   3/31/2017       0.49
3       A   3/31/2016       0.43
4       A   3/31/2015      16.13
5       A   3/31/2014       0.50
6     AAU  12/31/2018          0
7     AAU  12/31/2017          0
8     AAU  12/31/2016          0
9     AAU  12/31/2015          0
10    AAU  12/31/2014          0
11     AB   3/31/2019       2.68
12     AB   3/31/2018       2.30
13     AB   3/31/2017       1.92
14     AB   3/31/2016       1.86
15     AB   3/31/2015       1.86
16     AB   3/31/2014       1.79
17   ADIL   3/31/2019          0
18   ADIL   3/31/2018          0
```

By using the guidance given by @anky_91 in a comment below:

```
df2 = df1.assign(div_1yr_cagr=df1.sort_values(['ticker', 'date']).dividends.pct_change(periods=1,
                 div_2yr_cagr=pow(df1.sort_values(['ticker', 'date']).dividends.pct_change(periods=2) + 1, 0.5) - 1,
                 div_3yr_cagr=pow(df1.sort_values(['ticker', 'date']).dividends.pct_change(periods=3) + 1, 0.3333) - 1)
```

With this, I've gotten the below. The trouble is in the groups of tickers where there is less than 3 years of data, the above code fills in the cells with a -1.0, and I'd like these instead to evaluate to NaN (like when dividends are zero). Also, I only care about the growth with respect to the most recent date within each group, so is there a Pythonic way where the growth statistics are not calculated within each group for dates earlier than the most recent?

I've gotten:

```
   ticker        date  dividends  div_1yr_cagr  div_2yr_cagr  div_3yr_cagr
0       A   3/31/2019      0.626      0.113879      0.267206      0.455814
1       A   3/31/2018      0.562      0.137652      0.306977     -0.965158
2       A   3/31/2017      0.494      0.148837     -0.969374     -0.019841
3       A   3/31/2016      0.430     -0.973342     -0.146825           NaN
4       A   3/31/2015     16.130     31.003968           NaN           NaN
5       A   3/31/2014      0.504           NaN           NaN           NaN
6     AAU  12/31/2018      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
7     AAU  12/31/2017      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
8     AAU  12/31/2016      0.000           NaN           NaN     -1.000000
9     AAU  12/31/2015      0.000           NaN     -1.000000     -1.000000
10    AAU  12/31/2014      0.000     -1.000000     -1.000000     -1.000000
11     AB   3/31/2019      2.680      0.165217      0.395833      0.440860
12     AB   3/31/2018      2.300      0.197917      0.236559      0.236559
13     AB   3/31/2017      1.920      0.032258      0.032258      0.072626
14     AB   3/31/2016      1.860      0.000000      0.039106           inf
15     AB   3/31/2015      1.860      0.039106           inf           inf
16     AB   3/31/2014      1.790           inf           inf           inf
17   ADIL   3/31/2019      0.000           NaN     -1.000000     -1.000000
18   ADIL   3/31/2018      0.000     -1.000000     -1.000000     -1.000000
```

But would like:

```
   ticker        date  dividends  div_1yr_cagr  div_2yr_cagr  div_3yr_cagr
0       A   3/31/2019      0.626      0.113879      0.267206      0.455814
1       A   3/31/2018      0.562           NaN           NaN           NaN
2       A   3/31/2017      0.494           NaN           NaN           NaN
3       A   3/31/2016      0.430           NaN           NaN           NaN
4       A   3/31/2015     16.130           NaN           NaN           NaN
5       A   3/31/2014      0.504           NaN           NaN           NaN
6     AAU  12/31/2018      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
7     AAU  12/31/2017      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
8     AAU  12/31/2016      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
9     AAU  12/31/2015      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
10    AAU  12/31/2014      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
11     AB   3/31/2019      2.680      0.165217      0.395833      0.440860
12     AB   3/31/2018      2.300           NaN           NaN           NaN
13     AB   3/31/2017      1.920           NaN           NaN           NaN
14     AB   3/31/2016      1.860           NaN           NaN           NaN
15     AB   3/31/2015      1.860           NaN           NaN           NaN
16     AB   3/31/2014      1.790           NaN           NaN           NaN
17   ADIL   3/31/2019      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
18   ADIL   3/31/2018      0.000           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are the 1-yr and 2-yr growth of the second and third to last lines all NaNs?

Comment: @GZ0 they don't need to be, necessarily! They could be filled in as well, but what I'm interested in is the growth of the most recent dividend (in the case of AA this is on the date 3/31/2019 and CC it's 12/31/2018) with respect to whatever the dividend was 1-, 2- and 3- years ago (up to the maximum allowed given the available data.

Comment: @Convoxity If you only care about the most recent dividend then your expected output does not need to include other dividends and there might be more efficient ways than computing the percentage changes over the entire dataframe.

Comment: @anky_91 He needs percent changes within each group so `groupby` would be needed.

Comment: @GZ0 absolutely agreed on that, this is just to get the OP started since there is no try code posted. :)

Comment: @anky_91 I found my original try code so grotesque and un-pythonic that I opted to not even post it (looping through groups). Let me take a second look given your comments.

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for your initial help, it helped to further me along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that calculates only what you care about. It is based on the assumption that for each ticker there is exacly one row for each year.

```
df.sort_values(by=["ticker", "date"], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)

# Find date, dividends, and index of the most recent record for each ticker
# and populate result to the entire dataframe
df["index"] = df.index
df[["rec_date", "rec_div", "rec_idx"]] = df.groupby("ticker").transform("first")
df["offset"] = df["rec_date"].dt.year - df["date"].dt.year   # Compute time offset by year

# Copy relevant rows and columns into a new dataframe for further computation
mdf = df.loc[df["offset"].between(1, 3), ["dividends", "rec_div", "offset", "rec_idx"]].copy()

# Compute annualized growth and organize result into desired format
mdf["cagr"] = (mdf["rec_div"] / mdf["dividends"]).pow(1 / mdf["offset"]) - 1
cagr_df = mdf.pivot(index="rec_idx", columns="offset", values="cagr")
cagr_df.columns = ["div_{}yr_cagr".format(i) for i in cagr_df.columns]

# Merge the calculated numbers with original df to get desired output
result_df = df[["ticker", "date", "dividends"]].join(cagr_df)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @GZ0 -- didn't work right out of the box for me but after messing around with it for a little I figured a way to adapt your solution. Cheers

Comment: That's great. What aspect in your data causes the code to break? Or did I miss anything in my solution?

Comment: I was getting an issue when setting cagr_pdf with the pivot: an error about duplicates in the desired index "rec_idx" wouldn't let me set it. I worked around this in a really un-pythonic way, but I'm happy with the result nevertheless. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: IC. That indicates there are duplicates in (rec_idx, offset) pairs, which probably means your data do not meet the assumption that I mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be the case. I'm almost sure that there is only one row per year for each ticker, though admittedly I haven't sifted through the date row by row, haha. Was there another assumption I might've overlooked?

Comment: Did the error message explicitly tell you that there were duplicates? If not, what did the error message say?

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape  @GZ0

Comment: That is what I mentioned above. So you can examine the list `[keys for keys, g in cagr_df.groupby(["foo", "bar"]) if len(g) > 1]` to find the duplicate keys and check corresponding rows in `df`.

Comment: You can also compare it with `[keys for keys, g in df.groupby(["ticker", df["date"].dt.year]) if len(g) > 1]`.

Comment: Note that the first list is (most_recent_index, year_offset) pairs so you need some calculation to get the corresponding rows.

Comment: If you find multiple rows in the same year for a ticker then you need to consider to consolidate them into one row before computation, using `df.groupby(...).agg(...)`.

Comment: Let me look into this, I'm almost sure multiple rows would've been removed. Thanks again, GZ0!